# StimulSoft Report For ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, documentation, stimulsoft

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC Razor. I want to use stimulsoft reporter to get report from my data. I have added two dlls to my project's reference, but none of the online solutions works for me. I want a resource to learn stimulsoft for MVC Razor. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Stimulsoft User Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/), [Stimulsoft Programming Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/).

Look at the sample projects in Stimulsoft.Web distributive.

Comment: thank u buddy, I had read this article. In this article it says we should add a javascript file. I don't know how to use `@Html.Stimulsoft().RenderMvcDesignerScripts()` and what should I inport for this.